# jQuery colors plugin HSL model

Tags: jquery, colors

While I was trying to make a simple HSL to RGB conversion with [jQuery Color](http://enideo.com/code/jquery-colors-plugin/),

```
$.colors('hsl(100,100%,50%)').toString('rgb');
```

I noticed something weird in the HSL structure: the Hue can be set from 0 to 100, it does not accepts values outside this range,
so in theory `hsl(100,100%,50%) === hsl(0,100%,50%) === red`

But what I get after converting to RGB is `hsl(100,100%,50%) === red` and `hsl(0,100%,50%) === yellowish-green`
which would be true if the Hue would be 1-360 as in theory.

How can that be, and how do I get the full color circle using HSL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/Enideo/jquery-colors/blob/c7d791ba9545036b74747a6bf4f53de7067c20dc/src/jquery.colors.models.HSL.js#L45), the expected range for Hue is indeed 0-360.

> "the Hue can be set from 0 to 100, it does not accepts values outside this range"

That's because there's **a bug** in the [validation code](https://github.com/Enideo/jquery-colors/blob/c7d791ba9545036b74747a6bf4f53de7067c20dc/src/jquery.colors.formats.hsl.js#L18). That line should be:

```
if ((a == 1 && result[a] <= 360) || (a > 1 && result[a] <= 100)) {
```

`a[1]` holds the captured value for the first regex pattern (matching first arg, `H`), not `a[0]`. To illustrate, here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vMLZ2/

---

**p.s.** I've submit a [pull request](https://github.com/Enideo/jquery-colors/pull/1) with the fix. In the meantime, this demo shows the suggested modification working as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/Gh9kQ/

**p.p.s** The pull request [has been merged](https://github.com/Enideo/jquery-colors/commit/6ad62355257f33a773b813ee6588f49663d0096e) and should therefore be fixed in the latest version of the code.